# How to navigate to the corresponding java class from XML layout for fragments in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Suppose that I am in a layout file named "main.xml" and its corresponding fragment java class is "MainFragment.java".

Is there any shortcut to go to "MainFragment.java" from the "main.xml" or any other way?

It will be helpful to navigate around xml and java classes quickly when there are a lot of java classes and xml files in the project.

**Note:** For activity, there is a “C” symbol found in the top-left corner of the layout XML file. When we click that "C" symbol it will take us to corresponding java class in which the xml file is used. But for fragments, there is nothing available.

Comment: I know what you mean, although I don't have a solution for you; this would be similar to a common feature in MS Visual Studio where double-clicking an open  ASP.Net file takes you to the C#/VB.net code-behind

Answer (score 6):

You could right click on the file `main.xml` and in the options menu click `Find Usages`. You can then see all the places where `main.xml` is used.

Answer (score 5):

Use 'Related Symbol' (Navigate -> Related Symbol...)
In windows, press ctrl+alt+home, you can switch between activity/fragment and corresponding layout file

Answer (score 3):

Add to your root layout

`tools:context="your_screen_here"`

Then you can navigate directly by clicking to this blue button on left side (I'm using material theme, your icon and color can be different)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question then you must be looking for short-cut keys for navigating around all *.java and *.xml files in Android Studio IDE editor.

Here are few short-cut keys I use on regular basis which might help you out!

1. To navigate around any class files from any opened tabs -> ctrl + N
2. To navigate around any files (including class, xml, etc.) -> ctrl + Shift + N
3. To navigate through various opened tabs -> Alt + Legt/Right-Arrow Keys

Hope it would help you out!

Cheers!

Comment: He's looking for something specific and not just shortcuts in general. Hence, while your answer is generally useful, it doesn't address exactly what OP asks.